# MySQL query gives empty result when searching for word "other"

Tags: php, mysql, full-text-search

The following query gives no results, but it works with every other word (e.g. `+blue`). Is `other` a reserved word? If so, I can't find this in any documentation. I'm using MySQL 5.6 and PHP 7.3. By the way, I used to have a FULLTEXT index the style column that contains the "other" tag, but I removed it to troubleshoot this issue. It has made no difference.

```
SELECT * FROM products_master WHERE MATCH(category, subcategory, title, period, color, style, brand, more_tags) AGAINST('+other' IN BOOLEAN MODE) AND qty <> '0' AND replacement = '' ORDER BY id DESC
```

Update: I found that `+none` also gives no results, but `+empty` works fine.

Any ideas?

Comment: how common is the word "other" in your data? May disregard the most common words

Comment: `other` is a stop-word in MyISAM, but not InnoDB: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/fulltext-stopwords.html

Comment: My database is indeed MyISAM. I see both "none" and "other" on that list, so this must be the correct answer. However, I removed the FULLTEXT indexes on those columns and added regular Indexes. Why does the stop word list still apply?

Comment: This is a big problem for me. Using phpMyAdmin, I have removed all instances of FULLTEXT indexes in my table. Now I'm only using standard BTREE indexes, but for whatever reason, queries for guitar model abbreviations "SG" and "V" are ignored even though they are tags in the database. Of course, "other" and "none" are still ignored. Somehow, the FULLTEXT index has remained in cache? I have tried running FLUSH QUERY CACHE, but I'm getting a permissions error even though my only user has all privileges. I'm not seeing a way to fix this.